# Formula term-substitution in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let $F_u(s)$ denote the first order sentence with the term $s$ substituted for all instances of $u$ (where $u$ is any free variable). There is an exercise that asks me to define $F_u(s)$ for all possible formulas $F$ and then prove that $F_u(s)$  is a formula.

My book defines that if $F$ is a formula then let $(Qx)F_u(x)$ be a formula where $x$ is a bound variable and $u$ is any free variable of the language.

With the induction hypothesis that $G_u(s)$ is a formula for some formula $G$. (I have skipped the base case of the atomic formulas) I have defined $F_u(s) : = ((Qx)G_u(s))_v(x)$ iff $F := (Qx)G_v(x) $ where $u$ and $v$ in general are any free variable but could be the same variable and $Q$ is any quantifier). This can be proved a formula by straightforward application of the IH and the definition 'if $F$ is a formula then $(Qx)F_u(x)$ is a formula'.

However, I am in a debate with someone who thinks this it should be $F_u(s) : = ((Qx)G_v(x))_u(s)$. But, I don't see how my definition is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In predicate logic, *substitution* is defined in the obvious way for atomic formulas: $P(t_1,\ldots, t_n)[s/x] := P(t_1[s/x],\ldots, t_n[st/x])$, and we extend it naturally to manage formulas with connectives.

The only "tricky" case is that of quantifiers:

> $(∀y \varphi)[s/x] := ∀yϕ[s/x] \text { when } x \ne y \text { and } ∀yϕ \text { when } x = y$,

and similar of $\exists$.

In plain terms: if $F:=∀xG$, then the result of replacing free occurrences of $u$ with $s$ left the formula $F$ unchanged when $u$ is $x$.

---

Now, going back to your notation, we start with a formula $G$ with $v$ free. Then we quantify it to get $F := \forall x G_v(x)$ where we have replaced every occurrence of $v$ with $x$ [sylly example: $G := (v>0)$ and $F := \forall x (x > 0)$].

Now we want to apply the substitution: $s$ in place of $u$, and we have the two cases above: if $s$ is $x$, no substitution at all.

If $s \ne x$, then we have simply to replace $u$ with $s$ in $G_v(x)$ [silly example again: $G := (v+u>0)$ and $F := \forall x (x+u > 0)$; then: $F_u(s) := \forall x (x+s > 0)$].

If you adopt the convention that terms and bound variables are disjoint collections, the case $s=x$ cannot occur, and thus:

> > if $F := (Qx)G_v(x)$, then $F_u(s) := [(Qx)G_v(x)]_u(s) := (Qx)[G_u(s)]_v(x)$.

---

Regarding now the induction proof, we know that $G_u(s)$ is a formula by IH and we have reduced the case $F_u(s)$ to that of $[G_u(s)]_v(x)$.

But $G$ is a formula of lower complexity with respect to $F$ [removing the quantifier, we have to restore the original free variable $v$] and thus the IH applies: $G_u(s)$ is a formula.

Using again the example above with: $G:=(v+u>0)$  and $F:=∀x(x+u>0)$, we have that $F_u(s)$ is $\forall x [(v+u>0)_u(s)]_v(x)$ and the substitution $(v+u>0)_u(s) := (v+s>0)$ is correct by IH.

---

---

The feature of using two sorts of variables: $x,y,z$ for *bound* variables and $a,b,c$ for *free* ones (called: *parameters*), is common to the"tradition of [Proof Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory-development/); see G.Gentzen (1936), English transl.page 70.

How are they managed? We can see the rules for quantifiers in [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7):

> $(\forall \text I) \ \ \text {If } \Gamma \varphi[x/a], \text { then } \Gamma \forall x \varphi$

where $\varphi [x/a]$ denotes the operation of substitution, that is, of replacing all free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$ with a parameter $a$.

Thus, when we remove a quantifier we have to replace the bound variable $x$ occurring in the scope of the quantifier with a (free) parameter $a$, provided that $a$ is new (i.e. it does not occur in the formula).

This means that, with e.g. $F := (∀x)(x=u)$, the removal of the quantifier must produce $(v=u)$ and not $(u=u)$, because in the second case the re-introduction of the quantifier will produce $G := (∀x)(x=x)$, which is **not** the same as $F$.

Comment: Can you clarify your notation (Qx)(G_v)[s/u](x)? Does this mean substitute $s$ for any $u$ in G, then take this new formula and substitute $x$ for any $v$?

Comment: It's not my notation, I'm just following my book. I'm using Proof Theory by Pohlers. Also $F_s(u)$ and  $F[s/u]$ should be $F_u(s)$ and $F[u/s]$ meaning $u$ is replaced by $s$.

Comment: According to my book, a formula cannot be of the form $\forall x G$ for a formula $G$. (by the way he has $x,y,z$ as bound variables and $u,v,w$ as free variables, I understand other texts don't make this distinction) According to the author, first we must pick a free variable of the language (but not necessarily in the formula $G$), say $v$, and then replace that by $x$, which is denoted by $G_v(x)$, only then can we write $\forall x G_v(x)$. Now say we want to do $s$ substitution. Again, we pick a free variable to substitute for (which may or may not be the same variable we chose before)...

Comment: ...so this free variable could be $v$ again, or it could be a different variable $u$. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so in the new part you have written $F_u(s):=(\forall x)(G_v(x))_u(s)$ using my book notation. You substituted for $v$ first then for $u$. This is fine in that the result is a formula. But think about how would you prove this is a formula in general? The IH is that for some formula $G$, $G_u(s)$ is a formula, but we cannot use that in your case. Whereas if we let $F_u(s):=\forall x(G_u(s))_v(x)$ we still get the same formula but now we can use the IH to prove that it actual is a formula.

Comment: The answer to why $(Qx)(G_u(s))_v(x)$ is because it gives the same answer and it can be proved a formula easily. Can you add to your answer how to prove in general that $(Qx)(G_v(x))_u(s)$ is a formula using the IH that $G_u(s)$ is a formula? Because I don't see how.

Comment: I don't think this works. Firstly, $G_v(x)$ is not a formula according to my book. The IH is this: Assume for some formula $G$ that $G_u(s)$ is also a formula (where up to this point in the proof we have shown this for the atomic formulas and the $\land, \lor,\lnot$ connectives). However, since in the string $(G_v(x))_u(s)$ the $G$ and the $u$ are seperated, we cannot use this induction hypothesis.

Comment: If it helps I can send you the book I am using.

Comment: Wolfram Pohlers, [Proof Theory: An Introduction (Springer, 1989)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Proof_Theory/dbFqCQAAQBAJ?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=Wolfram+Pohlers+Proof+Theory+An+Introduction&printsec=frontcover)? I've browsed it.

Comment: Mine seems to be later version

Comment: @pmac - except for the "unusual" notation, there is nothing wrong with the book. Instead of starting with $(v>0)$ and quantifying it to $\forall v(v >0)$, the author starts from $(v>0)$ and produce $\forall x (x >0)$ which is $\forall x [(v >0)_v(x)]$.

Comment: Thus, as you correctly say, the key-point is to note that: $[(v+u>0)_v(x)]_u(s)=[(v+u>0)_u(s)]_v(x)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123934/discussion-between-pmac-and-mauro-allegranza).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $(Qx)[G_\mu(s)]_\nu(x)$ is not well defined (where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are any free variable). For example, Let $s:=v$, $G:= P(v) $ , $H:= P(u) $ and $F:= (\forall x) P(x) $. Note that $F \approx (\forall x) G_v(x) \approx (\forall x) H_u(x)$. Then

(1) $F_u(s) \approx ((Qx)G_v(x))_u(s) \approx ((Qx)G_u(s))_v(x) \approx ((Qx) P(v) )_v(x) \approx (Qx) P(x) $ .

(2) $F_u(s) \approx ((Qx)H_u(x))_u(s) \approx ((Qx)H_u(s))_u(x) \approx ((Qx) P(v))_u(x) \approx (Qx) P(v) $.

So the definition $F:=(Qx)G_\nu(x)$ iff $F_\mu(s) := (Qx)[G_\mu(s)]_\nu(x)$ is not well defined.

Instead define $F:=(Qx)G_\nu(x)$ iff $F_\mu(s) := (Qx)[G_\nu(x)]_\mu(s)$.

We will also use: (3) that for any forumla $G$, then $(Qx)G_\nu(x)$ is also a formula.

Now to prove $F_\mu(s)$ is a formula. (Parentheses will be dropped for readability).

I will leave out the base case proof for the atomic formulas. Define the length of a formula to be the total number connectives (including $\lnot$) and quantifier symbols. Now assume that for all formulas of length $n$ that the operation $_\mu (s)$ (for any free variable $\mu$ and any term $s$) applied to that formula yields a formula. Let $G$ be a formula of length $n$.

Note that $G_ \nu (x) \approx G_ \nu (\gamma) _\gamma (x) $ for any free variable $\gamma$. Therefore we have $(Qx)G_ \nu (x) _ \mu(s) \approx (Qx)G_ \nu (\gamma) _\gamma (x)_ \mu(s)$. Now put the extra constraint that $\gamma \not \in FV(s), FV(G)$ and $\gamma \not \approx \mu$ and $\gamma \not \approx \nu$ (we can always find such a $\gamma$ since there are infinitely many free variables).

Because of the conditions on $\gamma$ we now have $(Qx)G_ \nu (\gamma) _\gamma (x)_ \mu(s) \approx (Qx)G_ \nu (\gamma) _\mu (s)_ \gamma(x)$. $G_ \nu (\gamma)$ is a formula from the IH. Also, it is a formula of length $n$ since no new connectives or quantifiers were added. Therefore we can apply the IH again to get that $G_ \nu (\gamma) _\mu (s)$ is a formula. Then from (3) $(Qx)G_ \nu (\gamma) _\mu (s) _\gamma(x)$ is a formula which implies $(Qx)G_ \nu (x) _ \mu(s)$ is a formula.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I was wrong. Please let me know what you think of this proof.

Comment: I'm not sure to agree... According to your initial def $F_u(s)$ means "the first order sentence with the term s substituted for all instances of u (where u is any free variable). " In your example with $F := (∀x) (x=v )$ there is no $u$ free. Thus, the result of the subst operation will be: $(∀x)(x=v)$ .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for pointing out that mistake. I have provided a correct example. $P$ is a unary relation.